# Usage of sizeof in m_devget in 4.4BSD-Lite?

Tags: c, bsd

In the line 605 to 608 of `m_devget`, there is a code segment look like this

```
if (off) {
     cp += off + 2 * sizeof(u_short);
     totlen -= 2 * sizeof(u_short);
 }
```

What is the `2 * sizeof(u_short)` for?

Comment: Please add a reference or context to your question so that it is understood by future readers. As it stands, it is not a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

The function in question copies data from device memory into an `mbuf` structure.

If `off` (initialised to the `off0` parameter) is non-zero, it means that the packet being processed is trailer-encapsulated, so the code has to skip the type and length fields. Each of those fields are 16-bit wide. The code assumes `u_short` is 16-bit wide, as well.